# Java - Importing text file into array when lines are not consistent

Tags: java

I have an assignment that pretty much has me stumped early on, the remainder of which is fairly easy (sorting the data once its imported and then saving it again under a different name).

We need to import data from a .txt file into 3 separate Arrays ( name, mascot, alias ) however the lines are not consistent. By consistent I mean one line may have:

```
    Glebe,G Shield,Glebe District
```

While another line may have:

```
    St George,Knight & Dragon,Saints,Dragons,St George Illawarra
```

Everything before the first , belongs to the name array.

Everything after the first , but before the second ,  belongs to the mascot array.

Everything after the second , till the end of the line belongs to the alias array.

I've been able to work out how to import the .txt file where it contains the entire line, which I was then able to convert into importing everything before a "," and new line (using Delimiters). However the lines that contain more then 3 sets of data ruin the import as the alias array only ends up holding 1 not everything else.

Thus does anyone know of and can show me a code that pretty much does:

name = Everything before the first ,

Mascot = Everything after the first , but before the second ,

Alias = Everything after the second , till the end of the line

That I could use as a base to work into mine?

After a day of research I've constantly come up with dead ends. They all generally involve splitting up at each comma but that breaks the import (lines with more then 1 alias, the second alias is put into the name array, ect)

This is the code I came up with that imports the entire line into an array:

```
    public static void LoadData() throws IOException
{
    String clubtxt = ("NRLclubs.txt");
    String datatxt = ("NRLdata.txt");
    int i, count;

    File clubfile = new File(clubtxt);
    File datafile = new File(datatxt);

    if (clubfile.exists())
    {
        count = 0;
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(clubfile);
        i = 0;
        while(inputFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            count++;
            inputFile.nextLine();
        }
        String [] teamclub = new String[count];
        inputFile.close();
        inputFile = new Scanner(clubfile);
        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            teamclub[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(teamclub[i]);
            i++;
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\n" + "The file " + clubfile + " does not exist." + "\n");
    }

    if (datafile.exists())
    {
        count = 0;
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(datafile);
        i = 0;
        while(inputFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            count++;
            inputFile.nextLine();
        }
        String [] teamdata = new String[count];
        inputFile.close();
        inputFile = new Scanner(datafile);
        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            teamdata[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(teamdata[i]);
            i++;
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\n" + "The file " + datafile + " does not exist." + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done to split up the lines?  It looks like you are reading a file but not trying to do anything with the data you got.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method with the parameter `limit`.

When you have your input line in a variable called `line`, you can can call

```
String[] tokens = line.split(',', 3);
```

This will split the line on the commas, while making sure that it will not return more than 3 tokens. It returns an array of String in which the first element will be what is before the first comma, the second will be what is between the first and second commas, and the third element will be what is after the second comma.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to parse on the first 2 commas, you can use String `split` with a limit.

If you prefer, you can use the String `indexOf` method to find the first 2 commas, then use the String `substring` method to get the characters between the commas.

You want to be able to handle a line with one comma, or no commas at all.

Here's one way to parse the String line

```
public List<String> splitLine(String line) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int firstPos = line.indexOf(",");
    int secondPos = line.indexOf(",", firstPos + 1);
    if (firstPos >= 0) {
        if (secondPos >= 0) {
            list.add(line.substring(0, firstPos));
            list.add(line.substring(firstPos + 1, secondPos));
            list.add(line.substring(secondPos + 1));
        } else {
            list.add(line.substring(0, firstPos));
            list.add(line.substring(firstPos + 1));
            list.add("");
        }
    } else {
        list.add(line);
        list.add("");
        list.add("");
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method.

```
String line = // the line you read here

// Split on commas but only make three elements
String[] elements = line.split(',', 3);

// The first belongs to names
names[linecount] = elements[0];
// The second belongs to mascot
mascot[linecount] = elements[1];
// And the last belongs to aliases
aliases[linecount] = elements[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is split each line into an array as you read it in, and then parse the data line by line. Something like this (pseudocode):

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(datafile);  
while(inputFile.hasNextLine()) {  
  String line = inputFile.nextLine();  
  String[] lineSplit = line.split(",");  
  //TODO: make sure lineSplit is at least 3 long.  
  String name = lineSplit[0];  
  String mascot = lineSplit[1];

  //EDIT: Don't just get the last element, get everything after the first two.
  // You can do this buy just getting the substring of the length of those two strings
  // + 2 to account for commas. 
  //String alias = lineSplit[lineSplit.length() - 1]; 
  String alias = line.substring(name.length() + mascot.length() + 2);

  //If you need to do trimming on the strings to remove extra whitespace, do that here:
  name = name.trim();
  mascot = mascot.trim();
  alias = alias.trim();

  //TODO: add these into the arrays you need.  
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the Pattern/Matcher stuff -- you need to come up with an appropriate regex.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Something like this might do it:

```
static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^,]*),([^,]*),(*$)");
MatchResult result = pattern.matcher(line).toMatchResult();
if (result.groupCount() == 3) {
    // Found the groups
    name = result.group(0);
    // etc..
} else {
    // failed to match line
}
```

Comment: It's true. But it's a useful tool to have.