# .split and .indexOf on String[] array

Tags: java

My previous question: [Java - Importing text file into array when lines are not consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814983/java-importing-text-file-into-array-when-lines-are-not-consistent)

Every time I attempt to work .split or .indexOf I get an error message along the lines of: 'Cannot invoke split(String, int) on the array type String[]'. Eclipse isn't being much help, suggesting I change it to .length

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Club 
{
Scanner ConsoleInput;
public int count;
public Club() throws IOException
{
    String clubtxt = ("NRLclubs.txt");
    int i;

    File clubfile = new File(clubtxt);

    if (clubfile.exists())
    {
        count = 0;
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(clubfile);
        i = 0;
        while(inputFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            count++;
            inputFile.nextLine();
        }
        String[] teamclub = new String[count];
        inputFile.close();
        inputFile = new Scanner(clubfile);
        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            teamclub[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(teamclub[i]);
            i++;
        }
        inputFile.close();
        SplitClubdata(teamclub, count);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\n" + "The file " + clubfile + " does not exist." + "\n");
    }

}
public void SplitClubdata(String[] teamclub, int count)
{
    String[] line = teamclub;
    int maxlines = count;
    count = 0;

            while(count <= maxlines)
            {
            // Split on commas but only make three elements
            String elements[] = line.split(",", 3);


            String names[] = new String[maxlines];
            String mascot[] = new String[maxlines];
            String aliases[] = new String[maxlines];
            // The first belongs to names
            names[count] = elements[0];
            // The second belongs to mascot
            mascot[count] = elements[1];
            // And the last belongs to aliases
            aliases[count] = elements[2];
            count++;
            }
}
}
```

Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using a `List` ([ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is always a good option) to read in the lines? That would prevent you from having to read the file twice (once to count, again to store).

Comment: Eclipse is pretty much explicit "Cannot invoke split(String, int) on the array type String[]" which means your `line` is an Array of Strings and he is expecting only a String.

Answer (score 1):

`line` is a `String` array, you cannot invoke `split` on it. I think that you mean `line[count].split(",", 3)`.

I also suggest restructuring this class and use proper techniques:

- Don't read the files two times to get `count`.
- Use an `ArrayList<Club>` where Club has fields (`mascot`, `name` and `alias`).

Here is a cleaner version:

```
package org.argaus.gwt.tls.portlet;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Club {

    private String name;
    private String mascot;
    private String alias;

    public Club(String name, String mascot, String alias) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mascot = mascot;
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public static List<Club> ReadClubsFromFile() throws IOException {


        File clubfile = new File("NRLclubs.txt");
        List<Club> clubs = new ArrayList<Club>();
        if (clubfile.canRead()) {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(clubfile);
            inputFile = new Scanner(clubfile);
            while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                String[] parts = inputFile.nextLine().split(",", 3);
                clubs.add(new Club(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]));

            }
            inputFile.close();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\n" + "The file " + clubfile + " does not exist." + "\n");
        }
        return clubs;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMascot() {
        return mascot;
    }

    public void setMascot(String mascot) {
        this.mascot = mascot;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

split is called on a String object and not on an array of strings.

Probabaly this is what you should do :

```
// Split on commas but only make three elements
            String elements[] = line[count].split(",", 3);
```

instead of

```
// Split on commas but only make three elements
            String elements[] = line.split(",", 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `split()` the array, you can only call these methods on a `String`:

```
while(count <= maxlines)
{
  // Split on commas but only make three elements
  String elements = line[count].split(",", 3);
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods `indexOf` and `split` are not available on `Arrays`.

The fields/methods available for arrays include:

> The public final field length, which contains the number of components
>   of the array. length may be positive or zero.
>
> The public method clone, which overrides the method of the same name
>   in class Object and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of
>   the clone method of an array type T[] is T[].
>
> A clone of a multidimensional array is shallow, which is to say that
>   it creates only a single new array. Subarrays are shared.
>
> All the members inherited from class Object; the only method of Object
>   that is not inherited is its clone method.

See the [Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7)